# how to alter only one set of specific forms?

Tags: 7, forms

Consider I have 3 content type. The problem is that if I use form alter in a module , when I use:

```
drupal_set_message(t($form_id), 'status', FALSE);
```

in the mentioned hook, it shows me different set of form-IDs as message on showing each node add/edit form.

For example if I go to node type A add/edit form, drupal_set_message shows:

```
A_node_form
```

if I go to node type B add/edit form, drupal_set_message shows:

```
A_node_form
B_node_form
```

if I go to node type C add/edit form, drupal_set_message shows:

```
A_node_form
B_node_form
C_node_form
```

Showing them means that I can not really make an specific effect for each content type add/edit form by form_alter.

Note: I use OG module and B and C are the content types and A is the group type.

How should I solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the case you need, so you can easily use control flow in your hook_form_alter

You know that the hook runs everytime a form is willing to be rendered, so you can easily do something like

```
hook_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id){

if($form_id == 'A_node_form'){...}//alter form A

if($form_id == 'B_node_form'){...}//alter form B

if($form_id == 'C_node_form'){...}//alter form C

}
```

Comment: I edited the title of my question. As I told previously, my system checks almost all forms in each node add/edit form. and I really do not know where is causing this problem!

Comment: Your answer works for normal situations where system only checks a form related to the shown form.

Comment: Ok I understand check the answer again

Comment: Actually, it's a bug belonging to Pages and Panels, whenever I customize the node edit form it happens!

Comment: So in your code, whole conditions will be true for almost all forms, that's my problem!

Comment: you said "Showing them means that I can not really make an specific effect for each content type add/edit form by form_alter" you just need to understand something: Drupal hook_form_alter is called for every specific form before being rendered, so with those conditions you can ensure that your alters will be applied to the form you want. The 3 conditions CANNOT be truth in the same call to the hook.

Comment: I respect your answer, and really thank you for it.

Please test it: if your just make a module and write a drupal_set_message in a form alter hook, you can easily see it is only being used for the form which is going to be shown. 

But the problem for my system is with Pages bug, and I have already found an alternative for solving it.

Comment: Please test and you will see the form_alter is not used for all forms in each time. It is used only for the forms which exist in the page which is going to be shown. Please test, and you will see I am right. I have already tested it!

Comment: But my problem is only with Pages bug, and it checks all forms for any page! Even forms which don't exist in that page!

Comment: However I solved it, with using the arguments in the url . thank you for your collaboration